# how to increase or decrease Height and width of scrollview at runtime in android?

Tags: android

I have a scrollview which height and width is defined in xml file, but I want to increase or decrease the height and width of scrollview dynamically at runtime.

Actually I want to increase the height and the width of the scrollview 10 px per second for 10 seconds. But scrollView.getLayoutParams().height = GivenHeight using this code I can increase it run time only once. Can we increase it more than one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
scrollView.getLayoutParams().height = yourNewHeight; // in pixels
scrollView.getLayoutParams().width = yourNewWidth; // in pixels
```

EDIT to your new question:
If you want to increase this as time goes, you can easily achieve this by using a TimerTask and running it on a UI Thread, since we are touching it views.
I'll give you the code, since it's really simple.

```
int secondCounter = 0;
int delay = 0;   // delay for 0 sec.
int period = 1000;  // repeat every sec.
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        // do work inside ui thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do your work right here
                secondCounter++;
                yourNewHeight += 10;
                yourNewWidth += 10;
                scrollView.getLayoutParams().height = yourNewHeight; // in pixels
                scrollView.getLayoutParams().width = yourNewWidth; // in pixels
                //stop the timer when 10 seconds has passed
                if(secondCounter == 10){
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, delay, period);
```

EDIT:
To force view to refresh..

```
ViewGroup vg = findViewById (R.id.rootLayout);
vg.invalidate();
```

You will need to call invalidate inside the run method, after the new height and width has been set.

Comment: Using the above code i can increase height and width only one time but i want to increase scrollview gradually. For example i want to increase the scrollview height and width for 10 seconds with 10 px pixel increasing per second. Can we do that in android.

Comment: The effect is not showing in simulator but when i print the height of the scrollview then it shows that the height increase[Log.v("", "" +sv.getLayoutParams().height);]

Comment: Hmm.. try to force it to refresh by calling invalidate();

Comment: what is rootLayout in your third post answer?

Comment: is the root parent in your xml file, instead of "rootLayout", put whatever you named that to be in the id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollView.getLayoutParams().height = assignHeight;
scrollView.getLayoutParams().width  = assignWidth;
```